# Why are the vim line wise movement commands inconsistent?

Tags: key-bindings

While browsing `index.txt` looking for space to fit some custom keymappings, I noticed something.

```
^       - First CHAR of current line
N-      - First CHAR N lines higher
N_      - First CHAR N-1 lines lower
N+      - First CHAR N lines lower
N<CR>   - First CHAR N lines lower
N$      - End of line N-1 lines lower
```

Why the inconsistencies here, and the lack of coverage?

- `$` takes a number, while `^` doesn't.
- `_` without a number is seemingly the same as `^`, making `^` redundant.
- `<CR>` and `+` do the same thing.

Why isn't it something more along the lines of

```
N-      - First CHAR N lines higher
N^      - First CHAR N-1 lines lower
<CR>    - First CHAR N lines lower

N+      - End of line N lines higher
N$      - End of line N-1 lines lower
N_      - End of line N lines lower
```

- vi backwards compatibility?
- implementation details, something regarding count/motions, or how vim reads input?
- antiquated keyboard layouts?
- I overlooked some default mappings?

Comment: FWIW, these aren't the only movements that are redundant. For example, `0` moves to the beginning of the line, but `|` moves to the n'th character on the line, defaulting to 0 if not given a count. Also, `gg` is essentially `1G`